# withinkilometers geoquery in parse cloud fails with MongoDB error

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, mlab

I'm trying to get the closest Parse Object that is within 20 kms of a location.

```
  var testPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: fromLatLng.lat, longitude: fromLatLng.lng});
  var BKcity = Parse.Object.extend("BKcity");
  var cityQuery = new Parse.Query(BKcity);
  //Throws mongo error
  cityQuery.withinKilometers("location", testPoint, 20);
  cityQuery.find({
  ...
```

However query fails with:

```
�[31merror�[39m: Uncaught internal server error. { [MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 0.003139224611520954]
      name: 'MongoError',
      message: 'Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 0.003139224611520954',
      '$err': 'Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 0.003139224611520954',
      code: 17287 } MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue geo near accepts just one argument when querying for a GeoJSON point. Extra field found: $maxDistance: 0.003139224611520954
        at Function.MongoError.create (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
        at queryCallback (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:182:34)
        at Callbacks.emit (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:119:3)
        at null.messageHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:295:23)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:285:22)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
        at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
        at TCP.onread (net.js:523:20)
```

Query works on javascript, .near() query also works but not withinKilometers query.

Is this a parse-server bug or mlab issue or a silly mistake on my part?

Comment: what is your parse-server version ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about this. Turns out I messed up converting javascript string into float when setting up the geopoint.

Comment: can't remember exactly but just made sure it was a float.